# Using a List to Fetch Columns from a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, select, datatables, toarray

I can fetch columns x1, x2, and x3 from a DataTable (DT) successfully, using e.g.

```
Dim arrayOfObjects()() As Object = DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(b) {b("x1"), b("x2"), b("x3")}).ToArray()
```

However, most of my fetching will involve different combinations of columns, so in this case I would arrive with a list or string array of column names, and then would prefer to fetch columns based on the list or array.  How might that be done?  I haven't seen use cases where you can concatenate field names together in a string, and insert that into the Select command to fetch.

I am envisioning using something like

```
Dim mystr As String = "x1,x2,x3" 

Dim arrayOfObjects()() As Object = DT.AsEnumerable().Select(mystr}).ToArray()
```

Comment: `Dim tarCols = {"x2", "x3", "x4"} : Dim rows = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(False, tarCols).AsEnumerable().ToArray()`.

Comment: Thanks, but that produces a list of column names.   Instead, i need a jagged array()() filled with data from the three columns.  Basic idea is to concatenate a string and inject this into Select command somehow to get the data for the specified columns.  Basic problem is that `Function(b) {b("x1"), b("x2"), b("x3")}` cannot be replaced with a string or object.  Right now, i have this working with a DataView, but I have to loop over rows and columns.  Looking for a way to stuff a string or list(of string) into Select().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace:

```vb
Dim arrayOfObjects()() As Object = DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(b) {b("x1"), b("x2"), b("x3")}).ToArray()
```

With:

```vb
Dim mystr As String = "x1,x2,x3"

Dim tarCols As String() = mystr.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

' Shortcut
' Dim tarCols = { "x1", "x2", "x3" }

Dim arrayOfObjects As Object()() = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(False, tarCols).
    AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) x.ItemArray).ToArray()
```

To extract the values of any given one or more `DataColumn` and create that jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `DataTable` and added a few rows in the `Form.Load`

`Cols` is a `String` array of column names that I want in the new `DataTable`. The magic here is in the `.ToTable` method documented here [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataView.ToTable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```
Private dt As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With dt.Columns
        .Add("Number")
        .Add("Name")
        .Add("LastName")
    End With
    dt.Rows.Add({"Mary", "Ruth", "Morrison"})
    dt.Rows.Add("William", "James", "Patrick")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Cols = {"Number", "LastName"}
    Dim rows = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(False, Cols)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = rows
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpfull for loading a DataGridView with selected columns.